# Is CD tray opening and closing activity natively logged in Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, cd

I had a CD that I was working from in my workstation and want to know if the tray was opened by anyone else while I was away.

Does Ubuntu natively log CD tray opening and closing activity? If so, where would I check the logs?

Comment: My first instinct would be to check the man system logs via `tail -f` and then manually open and close the tray myself. If a log entry then comes up, look for the unique text that would identify that action and then `grep` the log for that text.